# In a rhombus/parallelogram what's the relationship between the corner angles at the four vertices and the angles at the intersection of the diagaonal

Tags: geometry, angle

In a rhombus/parallelogram/trapezoid do the diagonals bisect the corner four angles at the vertices?

Is it possible to construct a non-rhombus by putting four 3-4-5 triangles where the right angle is not at the intersection of the two diagonals?

The following is a parallelogram

[image]

[image]

Is there any relationship between the four angles formed at the intersection of the diagonals of a parallelogram and the four corner angles at the vertices of the figure?

Is this true or false, "The four angles formed at the intersection of the diagonals of a parallelogram are congruent." When is it true or false?

Comment: For parallelograms, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811308/in-a-parallelogram-does-the-diagonal-bisect-the-angles-that-they-meet. The diagonals of a parallelogram will bisect its angles if and only if the sides of the parallelogram are all equal length (aka it is a rhombus).

Comment: In the trapezoid, note that $\psi = \pi$ as alternate angles of parallel lines. Then $\delta = \psi$ iff the left leg and lower base are equal in length. Similarly $\pi = \Omega$ iff the right leg and upper base are equal in length.

Comment: https://graemewilkin.github.io/Geometry/Quad_Angle_Bisectors.html